# Not every $1$-nullset is an $s$-nullset, for $0 < s < 1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

For any positive real number $s$, define an $s$-nullset as a subset $A$ of the real line such that, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a sequence of intervals $\{I_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ having the following three properties:

1. $A \subseteq \cup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\;;$
2. $|I_n| < \epsilon, \forall \; n \in \{1,2,3,\dots\}\;;$ and
3. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|I_n|^s < \epsilon$.

It is not difficult to show that, for any $0 < s < 1$, an $s$-nullset is also a $1$-nullset.  I want to know how to prove that the converse is not true, namely, that for every $0 < s < 1$ there is a $1$-nullset that is not an $s$-nullset.

Comment: Cantor's ternary set is s-dimensional null iff s is at least $\ln{2} / \ln{3}$. You can modify the Cantor set to get such examples for every $0 < s < 1$.

Comment: Here's a note with a proof https://web.math.princeton.edu/~mdamron/teaching/F11/hausdorff.pdf